# how to get the previous route the user came from in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to get the url of the previous page I came from in react.

So if I came from `xxx.com/register`, and am now on `...com/profile`, then how do I log that in the console?

I have no clue where to start. Does anyone know how to do this? Is this possible in `react`? Should I use `js` instead?

Comment: if you are using react router then `history.goBack();` is what you are looking for.

Comment: but with history.goBack(), I cannot log that, because it takes me back to that page no matter what. I pretty much just want to log it, so I can use it in an if statement after

Comment: If you want to see where the user came from it is stored in `document.referrer`. This is not framework-specific.
If you want to keep the track of routes from within you app. Check out `react-router`.

Comment: @webduvet appreciate the answer! document.referrer works, but it isn't consistent within the app for paths. I think react-router would be better. Could you point me into the right direction for this one plz :)

Answer (score 2):

We can access the previous page using `useHistory()`

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

//...
const history = useHistory();

//...
    <div onClick={() => { history.push( 'pages/previous-page', { from: "previous-page" }) }>
       Previous Page
    </div>
```

On next page you can check by this code

```js
console.log("Landed on this page from ", history.location.state.from )
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you ask in the last sentence if you should use JS instead. React is a JavaScript library, thus you are already using JS and everything that you can do in your current version of JS, you can do in React.

Next, the History component is what you're looking for.

Here is a very comprehensive guide on history: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history.

Basically, you view the history, which is an array, from inside of your component. You can then either pull different values from the array or even push new values into the array, such as different pages on your website.

Comment: thanks for the response and clarification. I looked at the link you provided, and it says `state - (object) location-specific state that was provided to e.g. push(path, state) when this location was pushed onto the stack. Only available in browser and memory history. `So I tried this in my  code, doing `console.log(props.history.state)`, and it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?